# Conditionally enable/disable a Navigation Menu entry

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to dinamically enable and disable a menu item. There is an attribute to set it, but if I put a function in this field it is not fire.
[Enable/disable a menu entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2zDh.png)
Where and how can I set this attribute? I know it can be hide/show by condition, but I need only enable/disable.
The version is 21.1.6

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I succesfully set it by Application Items and Application Computations. I rewrote the function to return varchar2 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).